# Make VSCode trim whitespace-only lines, but not text lines with trailing whitespaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, whitespace, trim

I've been using Vim for a long time and recently switch to VSCode. In Vim I had the following setting:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/^\s\+$//e
```

This trims lines containing only whitespaces upon saving, while leaving other lines alone. I don't want to trim trailing whitespaces for text lines because it could be unexpected, e.g. for Markdown files where it could represent an intended line break (`<br>`).

How can I have the same setting in VSCode? `files.trimTrailingWhitespace` isn't exactly what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, not without the help of an extension, you can execute a find and relpace with auto-filled pattern via an assigned keyboard shortcut, but ultimately it would cost you 3 key presses (one to trigger the find query (with prefilled data) + one to exectue the replace + one to save document)